# Is it possible to make Camunda Webapps (Spring-boot stand alone) update .bpmn through Tasklist via DB or Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, camunda

We are trying to deploy Camundas webapplications as standalone spring-boot application and also deploy .bpmn diagram and engine in another stand alone Spring-boot application. But only connect the two SB-apps via a shared DB or REST-calls, and still be able to update the task through Camundas webapplications.

We have managed to deploy them and connect them to a file based H2 database. So now we can do rest-calls to the .bpmn Spring-boot app and submit forms etc. and then make it show in the Webapps-tasklist/cockpit.

The problem is that if we try to submit the form through the tasklist, we get an error that it’s trying to look for a javaclass (which we have implemented in the engine-SB-application but not in the Webapplications-SB-application).
Is there any way to make it so that we can use the web-apps-tools and submit the form from there (without changing that the .bpmn diagram uses java-classes)?
Either through making the webapps update the database, or maybe through REST-calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it by using Asynchronus Continuation. 
A very good video about can be found here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nx4I8lNMUs0